# Get value of variant field in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to access a custom variant dropdown field in a plugin inside the `commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem` event. How would I access the value of the dropdown, in order to do a comparison on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```php
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem', function(Event $event) {
        $purchasable = $event->params['purchasable'];

        $myDropdownFieldValue = $purchasable->getProduct()->getContent()->myDropdownField;
    });
}
```

Relevant event docs: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_lineitems.onpopulatelineitem

Comment: I've tried using that followed by:
    `if($myDropdownFieldValue == 'xxx'){
       $lineItem->price = 25;
      }`
But it seems to apply it to every variant, regardless of the option chosen.

Comment: If you add your full code we can probably help with that...